# Laravel 5 - scope in function with relations filters

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I was trying to get all Modules that targets the same **content** in their **managers**.

---

### Actually my code works, but it's not clean:

**AdminController:**

```
$this->manager = Manager::where('id',$this->id_manager)->with('fields')->first();

$managerSiblings = Module::with(array('managers' => function($query){
  $query->where('content',$this->manager->content);
}))->whereHas('managers', function($query){
  $query->where('content',$this->manager->content);
})->get();
```

---

### I want to do something like this, but i get an error:

*`ErrorException in Module.php line 36:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$manager`*

**AdminController:**

```
$this->manager = Manager::where('id',$this->id_manager)->with('fields')->first();

$manager = Module::with('managerSiblings')->get();
```

**Module:**

```
class Module extends Model {

    ...

    public function managers(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Manager','id_module')->orderBy('order');
    }

    public function managerSiblings( $q ){
      return $q->with(array('managers' => function($query) use($q){
        $query->where('content',$q->manager->content);
      }))->whereHas('managers', function($query) use($q){
        $query->where('content',$q->manager->content);
      });
    }

}
```

The problem is with `$q->manager->content`, that it's a property of AdminController. I don't know how to access that property from the Module Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to relations like this:

```
public function managerSiblings($content){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Manager','id_module')->where('content', $content)->orderBy('order');
}
```

Then when calling it in your controller, you just have to remember to call the get function like so:

```
$siblingManagers = Module::has('managers')->siblingManagers($this->manager->content)->get();
```

Haven't tested this code, so you might want to double check everything.

Comment: It throws an error `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, none given`

Comment: I try passing a closure and inside that put `$query->siblingManagers($this->manager->content)` But It throws the previous error: `ErrorException in Module.php line 36:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$manager`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I get `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string` I try almost everything and I get the same error.
Only works if I change $content with some string in the managerSiblings function. Also Throws the same error if I pass the string directly `Module::has('managers')->siblingManagers('note')->get();` strange...
By the way I am using scopeManagerSiblings to be able to use the function